# Paste Cropped image without changing color

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to add more elements to an image by merging it will cropped image. My code works fine but my cropped image upon merging doesn't retain color.

```
B = A(y1:y2,x1:x2);
subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(B);
axis on;
[rows2, columns2] = size(B);
promptMessage = sprintf('Click on the upper left point where you want to paste it,\nor click Cancel to quit.');
titleBarCaption = 'Continue?';
[x, y] = ginput(1);
r1 = int32(y);
c1 = int32(x);
r2 = r1 + rows2 - 1;
r2 = min([r2 rows]);
c2 = c1 + columns2 - 1;
c2 = min([c2, columns]);
plot([c1 c2 c2 c1 c1], [r1 r1 r2 r2 r1], 'r-');
A(r1:r2, c1:c2) = B(1:(r2-r1+1), 1:(c2-c1+1));
subplot(2, 2, 4);
imshow(A);
```

The final image has cropped image but the color of the cropped image changes.Please let me know how to retain the color of the cropped image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't retain colour because you are only extracting out the first channel of the image.  I'm assuming your images are **RGB** images, and so you need to also extract all channels at the same spatial coordinates.  Therefore, you need to slice into the third dimension as well:

```
B = A(y1:y2,x1:x2,:); %// Change
subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(B);  % Imange B is a cropped image with same color

plot([c1 c2 c2 c1 c1], [r1 r1 r2 r2 r1], 'r-');
A(r1:r2, c1:c2,:) = B(1:(r2-r1+1), 1:(c2-c1+1),:); %// Change
subplot(2, 2, 4);
imshow(A);
```

Comment: No its a gray scale image. like for example: eight.tif (Please find it on google as it is not letting me paste the link here due to size restriction). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then what you're asking doesn't make sense. How can a grayscale image have colour?

Comment: I just added the final output. Please check.. I want it to look like other coins in the image rather then blue color. Thanks.

Comment: Don't add it to my post. Add it to yours. I just did it for you. Also your code doesn't produce that example. Please include all of your code to reproduce that error. You aren't giving me the full story.

Comment: @ddesai - Can you upload the original image onto your post?  I can't reproduce your error.  Don't provide a link.  Actually upload the image into your post.  You have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @ddesai - Your image is actually an RGB image.  It looks grayscale, but there are **three** channels associated with it.  As such, put a `rgb2gray` statement at the beginning: `A = rgb2gray(A);`.  As I said, your image is RGB.... you have to at least **try** what I recommend to you before shooting it down.

Comment: Added original image as well. Thanks.

Comment: @ddesai - Just checked.  It's because your image is RGB... as I had suspected.  Make that `rgb2gray` call at the beginning to fix it or copy all of the channels.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for misleading you. But I am in process of learning Matlab and I would appreciate if you can explain me why the image is RGB and How can I find out as it looks like gray scale image to me.

Comment: @ddesai - Check the size of the third dimension.  If you did `size(A,3)`, you will see that the output is 3, which means that you have a three channel image.  You can do a simple check such that if this is 3, use `rgb2gray`... something like: `if size(A,3) == 3, A = rgb2gray(A); end`.

Comment: @ddesai - You didn't mislead :)  I've just been doing this a long time and I've seen this particular problem before.

Comment: @ddesai - The image was most likely saved as RGB because whoever processed that image or saved that image did it with some editing software and by default they all save images as RGB... even if the image contents are grayscale.  You have to specifically request that the image be converted to grayscale before saving... as such, one way to fix that problem if you want to work only on grayscale images is to employ that check I wrote above in my comment.